# Firebase security rules newData.val() compared to data.val()

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm an not understanding why this rule is failing the validation

```
".validate": "newData.val() < data.val()"
```

but this will pass the validation:

```
".validate": "newData.val() < 70 "
```

In the simulator I am entering the following values: 69, 70 and 71

In the first rule, the validation fails for all 3 numbers;
whereas the second validation it passes for the 69 value, as expected and fails for the 70 and 71 as expected...

Why doesnt the validation work for "newData.val() < data.val()"!?

PS i fixed the comparing string to integer as seen in the screen shots.

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what you're testing here. Can you share a screenshot of the simulator with the path you're writing to, the current data at that location, and the data that you're writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is gonna be dumb and mostly a rookie mistake, but I found my own stupid error!!!

In my security rules I had

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    "tokens": {
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < data.val()"
    }
  }
}, 
...
```

the 'users' had a lowercase u instead of the uppercase U that is my key in the data structure so the data.val() couldn't be pulled from the user as I was expecting...

Stupid mistake.... so please ensure to use the proper case as the security rules are case sensitive as I just found out!!!

PS the crazy part is the rest of the .read and .write security rules triggered correctly just the data.val() function wasn't able to pull the value... it would have been so much easier if Firebase denied all the security, would have likely found my error sooner... Firebase should close that gap!?

Answer (score 1):

If your new data value is a number, you probably don't want to compare it to a string: '70'.  If the new value is a string, and is entered in the simulator "Data JSON" box as a string (with quotes), like "70", then the validation `newData.val() < '70'` works.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I am starting to think you are correct on that, but you figure they provide a simulator that sits on the data and the security rules, and that it would use the actual value in the user token entry!? Why else would you provide a simulator in the first place if it cant evaluate the expressions prior to coding? I guess I will have to setup the code for this, I was looking to ensure the logic was correct before coding the app...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtoxRg-kbt0 this shows that it should be able to pull the value from the 'users' - 'token' as in the video it know that LA was not a value that existed but SF was!?

Comment: Good find. I'll try to reproduce his example.

Comment: @Learn2Code: Yup, your expectations are correct.  After further experiments, I agree that the simulator uses existing values in the database.  So can you provide more details on your failure case.  I can't reproduce your results.